# PHP, How to read only couple of rows from file

Tags: php, fopen, fclose

This is the insert into file, it puts 1 row at a time.
I want to read only last 10 rows, for example.

```
$file = SITE_ROOT."logs/log.txt";

        if ($handle = fopen($file, 'a+b')) {
            $content = Session::get('username') . " has logged out on - " . datetime_to_text("now") . "\r\n";
            fwrite($handle, $content);
            fclose($handle);
        } else {
            echo 'Culd not open file for writing.';
        }
```

this is how i read them, reads them all.

```
$file = SITE_ROOT . "logs/log.txt";
                                $content = "";
                                if ($handle = fopen($file, 'r')) {
                                    while (!feof($handle)) {
                                        $content .= '<li><a href="#">' . fgets($handle) . '</a></li>';
                                        echo count($handle);
                                    }
                                    fclose($handle);
                                }

                                echo nl2br($content);
```

How to read only 10?

Done, i found the answer i was looking for.

```
Thx, i found useffull this one.



$file = SITE_ROOT . "logs/log.txt";
$data = array_slice(file($file), -10);
$data1 = file($file);
foreach ($data as $line) {
echo '<li><a href="#">'. nl2br($line) . '</a></li>';
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tailing Log File and Write results to new file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16892270/tailing-log-file-and-write-results-to-new-file)

Answer (score 0):

```
 while (!feof($handle)) {
```

is the line actually "reading" the line so change it to this

```
$i=0;
$max=10;
while (!feof($handle) && ($i++ < $max)) {
```

that sets a counter and counts until $max is hit.
Sorry I missed the last 10. Only seen the 10 lines between the code blocks

[How to read only 5 last line of the text file in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961618/how-to-read-only-5-last-line-of-the-txt-file)

Gives great info for last x lines

Comment: yes, i figured this one out, but i want to read the las 10 entries.