# Display last entered data from CSV file in PHP?

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

I have a CSV file with an initial header row and an unknown number of rows. The row format is:

name_data, email_data, cell_data, dob_data

I'd like to open the CSV file and then depict the data from the last entered row in a table, like this:

```
Name: name_data
Email: email_data
Cell: cell_data
D.O.B.: dob_data
```

I'm thinking I can use fgetcsv() but I'm not sure how to parse the data once I get it.

Any ideas?

Thanks - Joe

Comment: example one on the maual page for fgetcsv is a great start

Comment: [What you want is tail information: Click Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16999819/1226894)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems inefficient to parse every line of the file with `fgetcsv()` when you only care about the first and last line. As such, I'd use [`file()`](http://php.net/file) and [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php):

```
$rows = file('data.csv');
$last_row = array_pop($rows);
$data = str_getcsv($last_row);
// loop and output data
```

**Note:** You can use the same logic for the headers by parsing `$rows[0]`.

Comment: The trade off from my version and yours is that your is piggish with space and mine is piggish with processor time. My second approach should be a good compromise.

Comment: Pretty sure this is even slower than parsing every line.

Answer (score 0):

```
$fp = fopen("csvfile.csv", "r");
// read all each of the records and assign to $rec;
while ($rec = fgetcsv($fp)){} 
?>
// rec will end up containing the last line
<table>
<tr><td>Name:</td><td><?= $rec[0] ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>Email : </td><td><?= $rec[1] ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>Cell :</td><td> <?= $rec[2] ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>D.O.B :</td><td> <?= $rec[3] ?></td></tr>
</table>
```

or if you anticipate the file being really long you can avoid having to walk each record by positioning the file pointer twice the maximum record length from the end of the file and then walking the record set.

```
$filesize = filesize("csvfile.csv");
$maxRecordLength = 2048;
$fp = fopen("csvfile.csv", "r");
// start near the end of the file and read til the end of the line
fseek($fp, max(0, $filesize - ($maxRecordLength *2));
fgets($fp);
// then do same as above
while ($rec = fgetcsv($fp)){}
?>
<table>
<tr><td>Name:</td><td><?= $rec[0] ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>Email : </td><td><?= $rec[1] ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>Cell :</td><td> <?= $rec[2] ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>D.O.B :</td><td> <?= $rec[3] ?></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Nice mention of the `fseek()` option. But you're making assumptions about the size of each line.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary True... but with knowledge of the data I think a safe and sane value can be found.

Comment: Added call to max on the fseek so we can make sure that the file pointer is never positioned before the beginning of the file.