# How to get last 1000 lines from a large file then remove them?

Tags: php, file

### Solved on 2 steps:

- Get the lines: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51350572/8524395
- Remove the lines after getting them: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51377052/8524395

---

I have a large file, I want to take 1000 lines from the end of this file, then remove them.

I am currently using this:

```
function deleteLineInFile($file,$string)
{
    $i=0;
    $array=array();

    $read = fopen($file, "r") or die("can't open the file");
    while(!feof($read)) {
        $array[$i] = fgets($read);  
        ++$i;
    }
    fclose($read);

    $write = fopen($file, "w") or die("can't open the file");
    foreach($array as $a) {
        if(!strstr($a,$string)) fwrite($write,$a);
    }
    fclose($write);
}
$goods = '';
$file = file("../products/".$PidFileName);
for ($i = max(0, count($file)-1001); $i < count($file); $i++) {
    $goods = $goods.$file[$i] . '<br />';
    deleteLineInFile("../products/".$PidFileName, $file[$i]);
}
```

I want to save the lines which I got in `$goods`

However, it times out because of the file size.

Comment: Are you running it from a browser or command line?

Comment: @user3783243 - a browser.

Comment: Please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451232/reading-large-files-from-end.

Comment: Do you need to run it from the browser? You won't have a timeout from the command line.

Comment: @user3783243 - Yes, it is a payment system.

Comment: I would recommend using a DB in that case. You're probably going to run out of memory with this approach, and deal with the filesystem locks.

Comment: @user3783243 - I want to take the purchased goods (1000 purchased good) from a file. What do you mean? :/

Comment: I've solved it temporarily by setting the max purchased goods to 400 - but no solutions for that? :/

Comment: Do you want to save the original input file after x lines have been removed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tailing Log File and Write results to new file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16892270/tailing-log-file-and-write-results-to-new-file)

Comment: Relevant reading, I think: [What is the best way in PHP to read last lines from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15025875/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get N lines from EOF, you can use [SPLFileObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php) (added in PHP 5.1):

```
$num_to_cut = 1000; // must be an integer and not a string
$new_file = new SplFileObject("limited_test.txt", "w");
$old_file = new SplFileObject('test.txt');

// here we get count of lines: go to EOF and get line number
$old_file->seek($old_file->getSize());
$linesTotal = $old_file->key()+1;

// and write data to new file
foreach( new LimitIterator($old_file, $linesTotal-$num_to_cut) as $line) {
    $new_file->fwrite($line);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! but is it possible to save into a database instead?

Comment: I think `$line` is what I should save into the database during the foreach loop, am I right?

Comment: @MatrixCow08, yes! If you want to save to DB immediately during foreach loop. Therefore, you even needn't open new file

Comment: But it still get 1467 lines and not the lines I entered in $num_to_cut ...
I made sure that the number I entered is an integer and not a string but same.

Comment: @MatrixCow08, how many lines do you have already and how many do you want to cut?

Comment: 2152 lines, I want to cut 1000

Comment: @MatrixCow08, oh, maybe you want to get last 1000 lines? then it should be `new LimitIterator($old_file, $linesTotal-$num_to_cut)`, and you'll get last 1000 lines!

Comment: I was about to do that already. Thank you very much :) I am trying now.

Comment: It worked great now! But should I use `DeleteLineInFile` function to remove the lines or it may cause the timeout again?

Answer (score 0):

### To remove the lines after getting them from a LARGE file:

The best way to do that is to use `sed` | But if you don't have access to use the `exec()` function then this is a function that you can use.

```
function replace_file($path, $string, $replace)
{
    set_time_limit(0);

    if (is_file($path) === true)
    {
        $file = fopen($path, 'r');
        $temp = tempnam('./', 'tmp');

        if (is_resource($file) === true)
        {
            while (feof($file) === false)
            {
                file_put_contents($temp, str_replace($string, $replace, fgets($file)), FILE_APPEND);
            }

            fclose($file);
        }

        unlink($path);
    }

    return rename($temp, $path);
}
```

Source of the function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2159135/8524395

To remove the line use it like that:

`replace_file('myfile.txt', 'RemoveThisPlease', '');`

- If you used **MrSmile**'s answer to get the lines, then replace "RemoveThisPlease" with `$line`